# inheritance and polymorphism in swift

Tags: swift, oop, polymorphism

I have the following problem:

Class A - super class.

Class A protocol:

has method ->

```
func test(params: GeneralParams, completionBlock: GeneralCompletionBlock)
```

GeneralParams is super class and has the following 2 subclasses: BParams, CParams.

now i have 2 more classes:

class B: A, A protocol

class C: A, A protocol

I want class B, C to use test function but with different class for their params for class B i want to use BParams and different completion block and for C the same thing. i want to have the same method for both with different parameters and implementation for both.

Whats the best solution for this situation?

Comment: If you have different parameters, you have different methods.  Unlike Objective-C, Swift allows overriding.

Comment: Your question would probably benefit greatly from an example use case of why you need something like this.

Comment: i want it to in order to have more concise code and same interface for both class. i will have a 3rd class soon which i want to be able to use same class name for all 3 with different params and different completionHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Since Swift allows method overload, the best practice here would be to overload a method to suite your needs in a new class.
For instance:

```
class B: A{
    func test(params: BParams, completionBlock: GeneralCompletionBlock){
        ...
        }
    }


class C: A{
    func test(params: CParams, completionBlock: GeneralCompletionBlock){
        ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats what i did but for some reason i had to keep the GeneralParams class and cast it afterwards, the overriding didn't let me use BParams in the fund signature.

Comment: @gal.orlanczyk that is my bad, do not include word "override", just overload/rewrite the same method with different params

Answer (score 0):

> I want class B, C to use test function but with different class for their params

The most important rule of subclassing is [substitutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). If B is a kind of A, then *everywhere* an A can be used, it must be legal to use a B. So every subclass of A must support this method:

```
func test(params: GeneralParams, completionBlock: GeneralCompletionBlock)
```

It cannot restrict this method to other types (not even to subtypes of these). If it did, then there would be places that I could use A, but couldn't use B.

B is free to extend A and add new methods. So, as @tmac_balla suggests, you can add an overload that will be selected for subtypes. For example:

```
class AParam {}
class BParam: AParam {}

class A {
    func f(param: AParam) {print("A")}
}

class B: A {
    func f(param: BParam) {print("B")}
}

B().f(AParam()) // "A"
B().f(BParam()) // "B"
```

But B must still support being passed the superclass.

Most of the time in Swift, this is the wrong way to go about things. Subclassing introduces lots of complexity that you usually don't want. Instead you generally want protocols and generics in Swift. For example, rather than A, B, and C, you would just have a generic A and a protocol.

```
protocol Param {
    var name: String { get }
}
struct AParam: Param {
    let name = "A"
}
struct BParam: Param {
    let name = "B"
}

struct S<P: Param> {
    func f(param: P) {print(param.name)}
}

let a = S<AParam>()
a.f(AParam()) // "A"
// a.f(BParam()) // error; we've restricted the type it can take

let b = S<BParam>()
b.f(BParam()) // "B"
```